# context.redirectToPage & $$PreviousPage

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

i have a button that is calling an agent , and i would like to return to the calling page as the last line of the button.

Is there a way to use context.redirectToPage()  in conjunction with "$$PreviousPage" instead of capturing the previous page via a before page load scope variable?

Thanks !

Comment: using this tip, i got it working.  http://xcellerant.net/2013/03/15/return-to-last-view/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to 'stay on page' use a partial refresh and eventually the standby control. If you want to get to the previous page you can chain simple actions. Action 1 would be 'run code' action 2 the redirect. 
You might want to check your response time. Converting your agent to a Java class will most likely give you better response times